# How to fix Temporarily unreachable in Google Webmaster tool or Console?

Tags: google-search-console, dns

I tried to fetch and render my site but I got a DNS site error(see screenshot below)

[image]

I attempted to fetch and render again after 2 days but still it gave me a temporarily unreachable status. But the website is definitely all active and working.

Comment: Check your plugins and scripts in your site.Disable plugins or scripts and test again.

Comment: We get this question a lot! This can happen from time to time. If your site is working okay for the rest of the world, then do not worry about it. Usually, these notices clear up in a few days. Just leave it alone for a while.

Comment: thanks for the relief reply @closetnoc since this was the first time that I experienced this kind of scenario so hopefully i can fetch again on google console thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please remove ( / ) slashed before the URL’s and then click on the fetch or fetch and render. For Example don't fetch (/digital-marketing-company.php) You have to fetch (digital-marketing-company.php)
2. The reason for your website being shown as 'temporarily unreachable'  in fetch as google as suggested by Google is due to some CSS or JS or Image blocking or taking more than expected time to load. When you try multiple times

Above two reasons may be you will get 'temporarily unreachable' error

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch a page with a redirect, you will have to follow it manually as described in the "Redirected". Optionally choose a type of Googlebot you wish to perform the fetch as. Click either Fetch or Fetch and Render.